# How to add and subtract weekends when adding dates in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, date

below is my code

```
  to_date('2021-01-05', 'yyyy-mm-dd')+15
```

If you add a date like this:
'2021-01-16' appears.

But the result I want is '2021-01-22', excluding weekends.

How can I get this result?

Comment: By weekends you mean only Sundays? Please, describe the logic with more details.

Comment: Saturday and Sunday sorry @astentx

Comment: If I count 15 days from 2021-01-05, excluding Saturdays and Sundays, it gives me 2021-01-26, not 22.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer to go with calendar table where you can have a flag value showing weekdays and weekend. Then it would be easy for you to query something like this.
**calendar**
|date |holiday_flag|
01-01-2021 Y
02-02-2021 N
.
.